# How to shuffle albums in EMMS?

Tags: emms

In the Emacs Multi-Media System, shuffling by song is as easy as <kbd>M-x</kbd>`emms-shuffle`, but i cant figure out how to shuffle by album, or to add a random album to the playlist. Is this possible?

Comment: I don't think that's a feature (yet), but it seems like it could be fairly straightforward to adapt the code from `emms-shuffle` to get that behavior.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an extremely crude function that will play a random album in EMMS.

```
(defun emms-play-random-album ()
  (interactive)
  (emms-browse-by-album)
  (goto-random-line)
  (emms-browser-add-tracks-and-play))
```

It depends on [functions posted to the Emacs Wiki](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/goto-random-line.el) by sburke@cpan.org.

```
(defun goto-random-line ()
  "Go to a random line in this buffer."
  ; good for electrobibliomancy.
  (interactive)
  (goto-line (1+ (random (buffer-line-count)))))

(defun buffer-line-count () 
  "Return the number of lines in this buffer."
  (count-lines (point-min) (point-max)))
```

I'm making this answer a community wiki as I'm sure it could be improved on.

Comment: thanks, I tweaked it [here](http://pastebin.com/pm0z9dw5) and it does basically what i want

Answer (score 1):

If calling an external Python script is not a problem, then give [Albumbler](http://kmkeen.com/albumbler) a try. The website lists EMMS support as "untested", and I haven't had the chance to try it myself, but it might work for you.

Comment: it does seem to essentially work, but album art is not displayed in the playlist buffer as it typically would be if you added it manually.